# using xcalib -i -a to invert colors in just *one* monitor

Tags: xorg, xrandr, colors, xcalib

For years, using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS,

```
xcalib -i -a
```

would invert the colors of just one monitor on my dual monitor Xorg setup. For that reason, I used both xcalib as well as [xrandr-invert-colors](https://github.com/zoltanp/xrandr-invert-colors), which successfully inverted colors on both screens. This worked great.

Now I have upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and suddenly **both** xcalib as well as xrandr-invert-colors invert the colors on both my monitors.

**Question: How can I use either of these tools to invert the colors on just one of my monitors as I have been doing for years?**

My xorg.conf:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "DontVTSwitch" "on"
EndSection  

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "sna" 
   Option      "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

Contents of /var/log/Xorg.0.log:

```
[    27.633] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.6
Release Date: 2017-12-20
[    27.633] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    27.633] Build Date: 25 October 2018  04:11:27PM
[    27.633] xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
[    27.633] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[    27.633]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    27.633] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    27.633] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Mar  2 10:18:20 2019
[    27.633] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    27.633] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    27.633] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    27.633] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    27.633] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    27.633] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    27.634] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using the first device section listed.
[    27.634] (**) |   |-->Device "Intel Graphics"
[    27.634] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    27.634] (**) Option "DontVTSwitch" "on"
[    27.634] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    27.634] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    27.634] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    27.634] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[    27.634] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    27.634] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    27.634]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    27.634] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    27.634]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    27.634] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    27.634]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    27.634] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    27.634]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    27.634] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    27.634]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    27.634] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    27.634] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    27.634] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    27.634] (II) Loader magic: 0x562f1a68a020
[    27.634] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    27.634]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    27.634]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[    27.634]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[    27.634]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    27.635] (++) using VT number 7

[    27.635] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[    27.636] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    27.641] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0166:17aa:21fa rev 9, Mem @ 0xf0000000/4194304, 0xe0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00004000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    27.641] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    27.641] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    27.650] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    27.650]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[    27.650]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[    27.650] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    27.650] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    27.652] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    27.652]    compiled for 1.19.5, module version = 2.99.917
[    27.652]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    27.652]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    27.652] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[    27.652] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics
[    27.652] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics
[    27.652] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics
[    27.656] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20171023
[    27.656] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.917+git20171229-1 (Timo Aaltonen <tjaalton@debian.org>)
[    27.656] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled for use with valgrind
[    27.658] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
[    27.658] (--) intel(0): CPU: x86-64, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, avx; using a maximum of 2 threads
[    27.658] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    27.658] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    27.658] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[    27.658] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    27.658] (**) intel(0): Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
[    27.658] (**) intel(0): Option "TearFree" "true"
[    27.659] (II) intel(0): Output LVDS1 has no monitor section
[    27.659] (**) intel(0): Found backlight control interface intel_backlight (type 'raw') for output LVDS1
[    27.659] (II) intel(0): Enabled output LVDS1
[    27.659] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 has no monitor section
[    27.659] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VGA1
[    27.659] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI1 has no monitor section
[    27.659] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI1
[    27.659] (II) intel(0): Output DP1 has no monitor section
[    27.659] (II) intel(0): Enabled output DP1
[    27.659] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI2 has no monitor section
[    27.659] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI2
[    27.659] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI3 has no monitor section
[    27.659] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI3
[    27.659] (II) intel(0): Output DP2 has no monitor section
[    27.659] (II) intel(0): Enabled output DP2
[    27.659] (II) intel(0): Output DP3 has no monitor section
[    27.659] (II) intel(0): Enabled output DP3
[    27.659] (--) intel(0): Using a maximum size of 256x256 for hardware cursors
[    27.660] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 has no monitor section
[    27.660] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VIRTUAL1
[    27.660] (--) intel(0): Output LVDS1 using initial mode 1366x768 on pipe 0
[    27.660] (--) intel(0): Output HDMI1 using initial mode 1024x768 on pipe 1
[    27.660] (**) intel(0): TearFree enabled
[    27.660] (==) intel(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    27.660] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    27.660] (II) Loading sub module "dri3"
[    27.660] (II) LoadModule: "dri3"
[    27.660] (II) Module "dri3" already built-in
[    27.660] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    27.660] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    27.660] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    27.660] (II) Loading sub module "present"
[    27.660] (II) LoadModule: "present"
[    27.660] (II) Module "present" already built-in
[    27.660] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    27.662] (II) intel(0): SNA initialized with Ivybridge (gen7, gt2) backend
[    27.662] (==) intel(0): Backing store enabled
[    27.662] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    27.663] (II) intel(0): HW Cursor enabled
[    27.663] (II) intel(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[    27.663] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
[    27.663] (==) intel(0): Display hotplug detection enabled
[    27.663] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    27.663] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[    27.663] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: va_gl
[    27.664] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 enabled
[    27.664] (II) intel(0): hardware support for Present enabled
[    27.664] (--) RandR disabled
[    27.666] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    27.682] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[    27.682] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context
[    27.682] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_profile
[    27.682] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_create_context_es{,2}_profile
[    27.682] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_INTEL_swap_event
[    27.682] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control
[    27.682] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
[    27.682] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float
[    27.682] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float
[    27.682] (II) AIGLX: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap backed by buffer objects
[    27.682] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness
[    27.683] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized i965
[    27.683] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[    27.685] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1366x768@60.0 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[    27.687] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1024x768@75.0 on HDMI1 using pipe 1, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[    27.693] (II) intel(0): Setting screen physical size to 361 x 203
[    27.723] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[    27.723] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    27.723] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[    27.723] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[    27.726] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    27.726]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 0.27.1
[    27.726]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    27.726]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[    27.726] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    27.726] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    27.726] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[    27.727] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    27.727] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    27.727] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    27.727] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[    27.748] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2/event2"
[    27.748] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    27.748] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    27.748] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    27.748] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    27.748] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    27.749] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event4)
[    27.749] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    27.749] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[    27.749] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[    27.749] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[    27.749] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    27.749] (II) event4  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    27.749] (II) event4  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[    27.749] (II) event4  - Video Bus: device removed
[    27.772] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input6/event4"
[    27.772] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    27.772] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    27.772] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    27.773] (II) event4  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    27.773] (II) event4  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[    27.773] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event0)
[    27.773] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    27.773] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    27.773] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event1)
[    27.773] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    27.773] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sleep Button'
[    27.773] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[    27.773] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[    27.773] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    27.773] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    27.773] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[    27.773] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device removed
[    27.804] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1/event1"
[    27.804] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[    27.804] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    27.804] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    27.805] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    27.805] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[    27.807] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/event5)
[    27.807] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[    27.807] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech USB Optical Mouse'
[    27.807] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: always reports core events
[    27.807] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
[    27.807] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    27.808] (II) event5  - Logitech USB Optical Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[    27.808] (II) event5  - Logitech USB Optical Mouse: device is a pointer
[    27.808] (II) event5  - Logitech USB Optical Mouse: device removed
[    27.852] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:046D:C077.0001/input/input7/event5"
[    27.852] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Optical Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 9)
[    27.852] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    27.852] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    27.852] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    27.852] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    27.854] (II) event5  - Logitech USB Optical Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[    27.854] (II) event5  - Logitech USB Optical Mouse: device is a pointer
[    27.855] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    27.855] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    27.855] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    27.856] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Integrated Camera: Integrated C (/dev/input/event16)
[    27.856] (**) Integrated Camera: Integrated C: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    27.856] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Integrated Camera: Integrated C'
[    27.856] (**) Integrated Camera: Integrated C: always reports core events
[    27.856] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event16"
[    27.856] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    27.857] (II) event16 - Integrated Camera: Integrated C: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    27.857] (II) event16 - Integrated Camera: Integrated C: device is a keyboard
[    27.857] (II) event16 - Integrated Camera: Integrated C: device removed
[    27.904] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/input/input17/event16"
[    27.904] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Integrated Camera: Integrated C" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[    27.904] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    27.904] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    27.906] (II) event16 - Integrated Camera: Integrated C: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    27.906] (II) event16 - Integrated Camera: Integrated C: device is a keyboard
[    27.906] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Mic (/dev/input/event9)
[    27.906] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    27.906] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    27.907] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Dock Mic (/dev/input/event10)
[    27.907] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    27.907] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    27.908] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Headphone (/dev/input/event11)
[    27.908] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    27.908] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    27.908] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Dock Headphone (/dev/input/event12)
[    27.908] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    27.908] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    27.909] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event13)
[    27.909] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    27.909] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    27.909] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event14)
[    27.909] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    27.909] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    27.910] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event15)
[    27.910] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    27.910] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    27.911] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event3)
[    27.911] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    27.911] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[    27.911] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[    27.911] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[    27.911] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    27.911] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    27.911] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[    27.911] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[    27.928] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/event3"
[    27.928] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[    27.928] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    27.928] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    27.929] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    27.929] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[    27.930] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event6)
[    27.930] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
[    27.930] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[    27.930] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[    27.930] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[    27.930] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[    27.930] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    27.930]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.9.0
[    27.930]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    27.930]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[    27.931] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[    27.931] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[    27.931] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[    27.960] (II) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: found clickpad property
[    27.960] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: x-axis range 1174 - 5768 (res 65)
[    27.960] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: y-axis range 790 - 5062 (res 100)
[    27.960] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: pressure range 0 - 255
[    27.960] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: finger width range 0 - 15
[    27.960] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: buttons: left double triple
[    27.960] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0x7
[    27.960] (**) Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
[    27.960] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[    27.960] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[    27.992] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5/event6"
[    27.992] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 12)
[    27.992] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[    27.992] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[    27.992] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.032
[    27.992] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    27.992] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[    27.992] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    27.992] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    27.993] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[    27.994] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    27.994] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
[    27.994] (II) config/udev: Adding input device TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint (/dev/input/event7)
[    27.994] (**) TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[    27.994] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint'
[    27.995] (**) TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint: always reports core events
[    27.995] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[    27.995] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    27.995] (II) event7  - TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint: is tagged by udev as: Mouse Pointingstick
[    27.995] (II) event7  - TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint: trackpoint device set to range 31
[    27.995] (II) event7  - TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint: device is a pointer
[    27.995] (II) event7  - TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint: device removed
[    28.048] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/input/input8/event7"
[    28.048] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" (type: MOUSE, id 13)
[    28.048] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    28.048] (**) TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    28.048] (**) TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    28.048] (**) TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    28.049] (II) event7  - TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint: is tagged by udev as: Mouse Pointingstick
[    28.049] (II) event7  - TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint: trackpoint device set to range 31
[    28.049] (II) event7  - TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint: device is a pointer
[    28.050] (II) config/udev: Adding input device TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint (/dev/input/mouse2)
[    28.050] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    28.050] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    28.054] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ThinkPad Extra Buttons (/dev/input/event8)
[    28.054] (**) ThinkPad Extra Buttons: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    28.054] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'ThinkPad Extra Buttons'
[    28.054] (**) ThinkPad Extra Buttons: always reports core events
[    28.054] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event8"
[    28.054] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    28.055] (II) event8  - ThinkPad Extra Buttons: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Switch
[    28.055] (II) event8  - ThinkPad Extra Buttons: device is a keyboard
[    28.055] (II) event8  - ThinkPad Extra Buttons: device removed
[    28.072] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/input/input9/event8"
[    28.072] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ThinkPad Extra Buttons" (type: KEYBOARD, id 14)
[    28.072] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    28.072] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    28.073] (II) event8  - ThinkPad Extra Buttons: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Switch
[    28.073] (II) event8  - ThinkPad Extra Buttons: device is a keyboard
[    28.556] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 728
[    28.556] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    28.556] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   75.20  1366 1414 1478 1582  768 772 779 792 +hsync -vsync (47.5 kHz eP)
[    28.706] (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 2966x1200
[    28.730] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1600x1200@60.0 on HDMI1 using pipe 1, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[    28.806] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1366x768@60.0 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (1600, 432), rotation normal, reflection none
```